# How to change output of array to column shape with new line

Tags: python, python-2.7, newline

I am trying the set that printed to demonstrate with new lines like in a column shape not row or list, so far I couldn't find solution.

```py
def two_sets():

    a = raw_input()
    n = set(raw_input().split())
    b = raw_input()
    m = set(raw_input().split())



    result = (n).symmetric_difference(m)
    result = map(float , result )
    print ("%s\n"%result) 

two_sets()
```

Output: `[11, 12, 5, 9]`

But instead I want to get out like this:

```
5
9
11
12
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instead -

```
result = map(str , result)
print("\n".join(result))
```